# 2行のテキストを含みフォントサイズを変えるUIButtonを作成したい

Tags: swift, ios, swift5

以下の記事を参考にしながら、2行のテキストでそのフォントサイズが異なるようなUIButtonを作成しようと思っています。

[Swift-2行のテキストを含むUIButton - www.it-swarm.dev](https://www.it-swarm.dev/ja/ios/swift2%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80uibutton/1053352290/)

しかし、Versionが対応していないのか、なかなかうまくできません。

よろしければご教授お願い致します。

Comment: あなたが引用されたリンクは本家stackoverflowの[この記事](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30679370/6541007)を勝手翻訳されたもののようです。このような勝手翻訳記事は元記事の最新更新を反映していないことがあるなど、問題がありますので、可能な限り元記事を参照された方が良いでしょう。(翻訳の質を見てもGoogle翻訳並みですし。引用先記事中には、一応鎖マークアイコンで元記事へのリンクが埋め込んであります。)元記事の承認回答中で **Swift 5** と記されたコードはわずかな書き換えで動くようにできました。あなたは何をどうやって、どんな問題が出ているのでしょうか。ご質問を編集してその辺りをご説明いただくと回答が書きやすくなるのですが。

Comment: 私は swift5 で次の code で指定フォントサイズで２行表示しています。
btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)

Comment: ```newlineRange.location```といところがうまくいきませんでした、

Comment: あなたの採用されたコードがどんなものかわからない状態で、「`newlineRange.location`」とコードの一部を引用されても何が起こっているのかは読むものには判断できないです。コードの問題であるなら、ご質問内に現在使用しているコードを掲載してください。その上で該当箇所がビルド時にエラーになるのか、実行時にエラーになるのか、それともそれ以外なのか、具体的な説明をお願いします。単に「うまくいきません」と言うのは、それ以外の情報が十分に示されていないときには、ほとんど意味をなさない言葉です。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UIButton with two lines of text  - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679370/swift-uibutton-with-two-lines-of-text) の回答を参考にすることで解決しました！

```
Btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
Btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
Btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center

let buttonText: NSString = "hello\nthere"
let newlineRange: NSRange = buttonText.range(of: "\n")
var substring1 = ""
var substring2 = ""

if(newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
    substring1 = buttonText.substring(to: newlineRange.location)
    substring2 = buttonText.substring(from: newlineRange.location)
}

let font1: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 17.0)!
let attributes1 = [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: font1]
let attrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring1, attributes: attributes1)

let font2: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 11.0)!
let attributes2 = [NSMutableAttributedString.Key.font: font2]
let attrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: substring2, attributes: attributes2)

attrString1.append(attrString2)

//assigning the resultant attributed strings to the button
Btn.setAttributedTitle(attrString1, for: [])
```